# Example of a $T_1$ space that does not have the property that every compact subspace of $X$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ denote a topological space. Then each condition in the following list implies the next.

1. $X$ is $T_2$
2. Every compact subspace of $X$ is closed.
3. $X$ is $T_1$.

I know that 2 does not imply 1 (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328725/if-every-compact-set-is-closed-then-is-the-space-hausdorff)). I'm also guessing that 3 does not imply 2. Does anyone know of an example?

Comment: I'll just mention that the name [KC-space](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22KC+space%22+compact) is sometimes used for such spaces (see also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955382/spaces-where-all-compact-subsets-are-closed/955418#955418)). There were [several posts](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22KC-spaces%22+site:math.stackexchange.com) about such spaces on this site.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks. I wonder why $T_{1\frac{1}{2}}$ never caught on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One example is the co-finite topology on any infinite set $X$. Since any nonempty open set omits at most finitely many points, *every* subset is compact. However any proper infinite subset is not closed, so there are compact subsets which are not closed.  (This space is clearly T<sub>1</sub> since all finite subsets are closed by definition.)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the simplest example is to let $p$ and $q$ be distinct points not in $\Bbb N$, let $X=\Bbb N\cup\{p,q\}$, make each point of $\Bbb N$ isolated, and give $p$ and $q$ open nbhds as follows. A set $U\subseteq X$ is an open nbhd of $p$ iff $p\in U$ and $\Bbb N\setminus U$ is finite, and $U$ is an open nbhd of $q$ iff $q\in U$ and $\Bbb N\setminus U$ is finite. Essentially we’ve just made $\Bbb N$ a sequence with two limit points, $p$ and $q$. It’s easy to check that $X$ is $T_1$, but $\{p\}\cup\Bbb N$ and $\{q\}\cup\Bbb N$ are compact sets that aren’t closed: they’re both dense in $X$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675504/us-does-not-imply-ab/999207#999207) has a slightly more complicated example in which all convergent sequences have unique limits. And [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/466564/12042) has another more complicated example.

Answer (score 1):

What about $X=\Bbb N$ with cofinite topology?